# How to toggle the element that I got with json?

Tags: jquery, json

I made a page that append json data with jquery as seen below. The thing I want to do is, toggling the description parts when clicking each image. I wrote a click function as you see, but it didn't work. What should I do?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Your callback needs a variable to store the data in
  $.getJSON('http://ahmetgo.co.nf/l/film.json', function(data) {
    // data is your entire object, data.movies is an array
    for (var i = 0; i < data.movies.length; i++) {
      // .html() will *replace* the HTML, you want to .append()
      $('.kutu').append('<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><img id="res' + i + '" src="' + data.movies[i].image + '"><br><br><p class="dc" id="d' + i + '">' + data.movies[i].description + '</p></div>');

      $("#res" + i).click(function() {

          $("#d" + i).toggle();
        }


      );

    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: gray;
}
.container-fluid {
  padding-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <!--BOOTSTRAP CSS-->
  <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!--BOOTSTRAP JS-->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <!--JQUERY JS-->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>

  <!--Main JS-->
  <script src="main.js"></script>

  <title></title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row kutu">


    </div>


  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many methods that can make this process far less arduous. For starters, it's not a good practice to attach event handlers within a `for` loop (or any loop for that matter, pun intended).

Instead, we can extract that logic and place it outside for delegation (which is the norm especially when manipulating dynamic DOM elements).

Here's one way you can achieve your goal without too much fiddling:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Delegate your toggle handler to any elements appended to the DOM
  $('img[data-toggle]').on('click', function () {
    // Toggle the target element set out in the data attribute
    $($(this).data('toggle')).toggle();
  });

  // Your callback needs a variable to store the data in
  $.getJSON('http://ahmetgo.co.nf/l/film.json', function(data) {
    // data is your entire object, data.movies is an array
    for (var i = 0; i < data.movies.length; i++) {
      // .html() will *replace* the HTML, you want to .append()
      // NOTE: All you are adding is the data-toggle to reference the <p> element
      $('.kutu').append('<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><img data-toggle="#d' + i + '" id="res' + i + '" src="' + data.movies[i].image + '"><br><br><p class="dc" id="d' + i + '">' + data.movies[i].description + '</p></div>');
    }
  });
});
```

In a nutshell, you're adding a data attribute to the image which simply references the ID (note: including the #) of the element you wish to toggle. This way you can keep the event binding logic outside of the loop and will toggle all present and future elements with said attribute.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I didn't get what attr to change in the lines you added. Where will I description id for instance?

Comment: Your description ID should still apply to the `<p>` element (as is currently). You're just adding the `data-toggle="#d' + i + '"` attribute to the `<img>` so that the function knows what description it's meant to toggle and only that description will be toggled.